# Rails unobtrusive javascript - Failed to load resource

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm trying to add new objects using AJAX, but all I get is "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)".

I've spent about 4 hours trying to find solution, followed 2 tutorials, but that error never left me.

My characters_controller.rb

```
class CharactersController < ApplicationController

def index
    @characters = Character.all.order("id DESC")
end

def create
    @character = Character.new(params[:character])

    if @character.save  
        flash[:notice] = "Successfully created post."
    end

    respond_to do |format|
        format.js
    end
end
end
```

index.html.erb

```
<div class="header">
    <p>All Hobbit characters</p>
</div>

<div class="characters">
    <%= render @characters %>
</div>

<%= form_for(Character.new, :remote => true) do |f| %>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :name %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :name %>
    </div>
    <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

create.js.erb

```
<% if @character.new_record? %>
    $('input#character_name').effect('highlight', {color: 'red'});
<% else %>
    $('div#characters').append("<%= escape_javascript(render @character) %>");
    $('div#<%= dom_id(@character) %>').effect('highlight');
<% end %>
```

Model only contains :name presence validation

Comment: If you check log/development.log, there will be more details regarding what caused the 500.  Do you have a partial view for app/views/characters/_character.html.erb ?

Comment: Thanks, log shows: ForbiddenAttributesError and line is: @character = Character.new(params[:character])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Rails 4, you can't pass `params[:character]` directly to the `Character.new` method.  Try something like this:

```
def create
    @character = Character.new(character_params)
    if @character.save  
        flash[:notice] = "Successfully created post."
    end
    respond_to do |format|
        format.js
    end
end

private

def character_params
  params.require(:character).permit(:name)
end
```